# cron実行したらメールを受け取りたい

Tags: centos, cron

**現状**
・cron実行されるがメールを受信できない

---

**試したこと1**

```
/etc/cron.d/hoge
```

> MAILTO="メールアドレス"

```
systemctl restart crond
```

---

**試したこと2**
・/etc/crontabはデフォルトのままですが、ここに書かなければいけないのかと思い、下記へ変更したのですが、メール受信できません

> MAILTO="メールアドレス"

```
systemctl restart crond
```

---

**試したこと3**
/var/spool/mail/を見たのですが、メールは溜まっていないと思います(見方が良くわからない)

---

**Q**
・cronメールを受信できない場合はどこを確認するのですか？

---

**環境**
・CentOS7

---

**追記**
・cron内容は/etc/cron.d/hogeファイルに記載しています
・phpファイルを実行させ、結果としてhtmlを出力させています

```
2 6 * * * root /usr/bin/php /var/www/中略/hoge.php
```

Comment: Cronではどういうスクリプトが実行されてどういう出力がありますか？

Comment: cronで実行するコマンドはどちらのファイルに設定されてますか？あと postfix のキューに溜まってませんでしょうか？ postqueue -p でキューの中身を確認できると思います。/var/log/maillog にもメール送信エラーなどが出力されてるかもしれませんので確認してみてください。

Comment: cron内容を本文に追記しました

Comment: 「# postqueue -p」すると「bash: postqueue: コマンドが見つかりません」と表示されました。/var/log/maillog 内容は空でした

Comment: hoge.phpコマンドは標準出力or標準エラー出力に何か結果を出力するでしょうか? 出力がある場合のみMAILTOにメールされると思いますのでご確認ください。

Comment: `/var/log/cron` は確認しましたか?

Comment: MTA が Postfix なら `postqueue` は `/sbin/postqueue` にあります。パスが通っていないようなのでフルパスで実行しましょう。もしくは MTA の種類に依存しない `mailq` (`/usr/bin/mailq`) コマンドをどうぞ。MTA が何かの確認は `/usr/sbin/update-alternatives --display mta` で。

Comment: hoge.phpに「ini_set('display_errors',1);」と記述しているので、出力される設定になっていると思います

Comment: /var/log/cronは、初めて確認しました。分からないことがたくさんあるので、この件については別途質問します

Comment: /sbin/に中にpostqueueはありませんでした。/usr/sbin/update-alternatives --display mta実行したのですが、何も表示されませんでした。mailqコマンドも内容難しかったです。そもそもの大前提として、CentOS7のデフォルト状態では、cronメールは受信できないのでしょうか？ まずはmtaを設定しなければいけない、ということですか？？

Comment: hoge.phpはecho等で標準出力に何か結果を出力していますか？